# Mehrdeutigkeit von »nicht wollen« umgehen

Tags: meaning-in-context

Die Aussage

> Ich wollte das nicht.

ist leider mehrdeutig, und ich würde gerne wissen, wie man diesen Satz ohne lange Reden eindeutiger machen könnte.

---

Zwei Beispiele sollen die Mehrdeutigkeit zeigen:

1. Erwin versteht sich nicht besonders gut mit seiner Schwiegermutter. Hätte seine Frau Andrea vorgeschlagen zu ihr zu fahren, hätte er abgelehnt. Andrea weiß das natürlich. Sie hat sich daher, ohne Erwins Wissen, bei ihrer Mutter angemeldet und Erwin damit überrumpelt. Beide besuchen gemeinsam Andreas Mutter. Nach Kaffee und Kuchen, als Andreas Mutter das Ehepaar kurz für einen Moment allein lässt, mahnt Andrea ihrem Mann, doch nicht die ganze Zeit so ein mürrisches Gesicht zu machen. Erwin antwortet:

   > Ich wollte nicht hierher fahren, das war deine Idee.

   Damit versucht Erwin auszudrücken, dass er von Anfang an gegen die Reise war, und dass niemand vor ihm erwarten könne, jetzt auch noch Fröhlichkeit zu simulieren. Es ist Andreas Schuld, dass er hier sein muss, und jetzt soll sie auch gefälligst mit seiner miesen Laune klarkommen.
2. Markus ist in Salzburg aufgewachsen, lebt aber, seit er Eva geheiratet hat, in Evas Geburtsstadt München. Als Eva und Markus sich überlegen, was sie nächstes Wochenende machen könnten, schlägt Eva vor, doch wieder mal nach Salzburg zu fahren. Sie will Markus damit eine Freude machen, spricht diese Motivation aber nicht explizit aus. Markus, der zwar andere Ideen hatte, aber auch schon lange nicht mehr in seiner Heimatstadt war, nimmt den Vorschlag an. Als dann beide durch Salzburg spazieren, zeigt Markus aber nicht die Euphorie, die sich Eva erwartet hat. Eva fragt Markus, warum er sich denn nicht mehr freut wieder in Salzburg zu sein, schließlich seien die beiden ja nur wegen ihm hier. Markus antwortet:

   > Ich wollte nicht hierher fahren, das war deine Idee.

   Damit versucht Markus auszudrücken, dass die beiden keineswegs seinetwegen hier sind. Er ist gern in Salzburg, er fand Evas Vorschlag auch gut, aber es war nicht sein Vorschlag, sondern ihrer. Eva versteht den Satz aber so, wie ihn Erwin im ersten Beispiel gemeint hat und ist nun sauer.

---

Meine Frage:

Mit welcher ähnlich kurzer Formulierung kann man einen Satz wie

> Ich wollte das nicht.

ersetzen, so dass eindeutig klar ist, ob damit etwas wie im ersten oder wie im zweiten Beispiel gemeint ist.

Anders formuliert:

Was hätte Markus im zweiten Beispiel sagen müssen, um ein Missverständnis zu vermeiden?

Comment: Meinst du den Unterschied zwischen "gegen etwas sein" und "nicht für etwas sein", also den Unterschied zwischen "starke Meinung gegen etwas" und möglicherweise "überhaupt keine Meinung dazu"?

Comment: @tofro: Ja, du hast es auf den Punkt gebracht.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das ist ein kleines sprachlich/logisches Dilemma, das du hier beschreibst:

"nicht wollen" heißt eben nicht unbedingt "dagegen sein", sondern kann auch "keine Meinung dazu haben" bedeuten (das ist i.Ü. kein spezifisches Problem der deutschen Sprache, sondern tritt so in fast allen anderen Sprachen auch auf). Die Umgehung von solchen Mißverständnissen mit deutschen Sprachmitteln ist aber dann auch wieder spezifisch für die Sprache.

"Ich wollte nicht" kann in jedem Fall aufgefasst werden als "Ich war dagegen" (auch wenn die formale Logik nach Aristoteles das anders sehen würde) und sollte deshalb in Fällen wie deinem zweiten Beispiel nicht verwendet werden.

Markus sollte also auf jeden Fall klarstellen, dass er keine besondere Meinung zu Salzburg hat und nicht etwa dagegen war, hierherzufahren - Am diplomatischsten würde er sich wohl aus der Affäre ziehen, wenn er antworten würde:

> Ich weiß, dass du mir mit Salzburg eine Freude machen wolltest, mir liegt aber nicht mehr dran als an jeder anderen Stadt - ich wäre gerne auch woanders hin gefahren.

Damit macht er klar, dass er Evas gute Absichten anerkennt, aber auch, dass ihm an dem Besuch in Salzburg nicht mehr liegt als an jedem anderen Reiseziel. Eva wird aber in jedem Fall beleidigt sein: Frauen sind so ;)

Answer (score 4):

Der Unterschied in der Bedeutung ist hier subtil, deswegen ist es schwer, das mit einer kurzen Formulierung kenntlich zu machen. Die Gefahr, dass die Aussage im zweiten Fall falsch aufgefasst wird, liegt aber auch an der Formulierung "das war deine Idee", die im Kontext wie eine Anschuldigung klingt. Eine Möglichkeit, die Intention zu verdeutlichen, wäre folgende:

> Ich wollte nicht unbedingt hierher fahren, das war deine Idee.

*Unbedingt* als Adverb drückt hier aus, dass Markus zwar nicht dagegen war, nach Salzburg zu fahren, es aber auch nicht seine erste Wahl war. Das löst natürlich nicht das Problem, dass Eva von seiner ausbleibenden Euphorie enttäuscht sein kann.

Answer (score 4):

Die Mehrdeutigkeit kommt erst dadurch zustande, dass man zu viel nachdenkt und beim Lesen künstlich den Rhythmus und die Intonation ändert.

Wenn ich den Satz

> Ich wollte nicht hierher fahren, das war deine Idee.

*ohne nachzudenken* lese, dann hebe ich automatisch die Stimme bei den Wörtern *wollte* und *deine*. Daher würde ich den Satz immer im erstgenanntem Sinne interpretieren.

Im Satz

> Nicht ich wollte hierher fahren, das war deine Idee.

würde ich automatisch die Stimme bei den Wörtern *ich* und *deine* heben und ihn dadurch im zweitgenanntem Sinne interpretieren. Persönlich würde ich anstelle des Kommas einen Gedankenstrich setzen, um den Gegensatz hervorzuheben:

> Nicht ich wollte hierher fahren - das war deine Idee.

Durch die längere Sprechpause senkt man automatisch die Stimme beim Wort *fahren*.

Comment: Wie genau sprichst du den Gedankenstrich aus? Klingt er anders als ein Komma? Ich frage, weil du in deiner Antwort explizit Betonungen thematisierst.

Comment: Mit Komma würde ich, andere aber vielleicht nicht, die Stimme beim Wort *fahren* oben lassen und nach kurzer Pause weiterlesen. Mit Gedankenstrich würde ich die Stimme beim Wort *fahren* automatisch senken und die Pause etwas länger machen. Am besten wäre es, wenn ich hier beide Varianten vorlesen könnte, aber ich hoffe, meine Erläuterungen sind verständlich genug.

Comment: Mit deinem ersten Satz bin ich nicht bei dir. Meiner Erfahrung nach ist die Anzahl der Menschen, die "zu viel denken", vernachlässigbar gering. Mir begegnet nur ständig das Gegenteil...

Answer (score 3):

Es wundert mich etwas, dass das Beispiel auf "nicht wollen" beschränkt ist. Das Problem ist nämlich allgemeiner. Die Mehrdeutigkeit liegt schon im "nicht". Besonders deutlich wird das bei den beiden möglichen Bedeutungen des berühmten Satzes "Glauben heißt nicht wissen":

> ```
> "Glauben" heißt  nicht "wissen"
> "Glauben" heißt "nicht  wissen"
> ```

Man könnte vielleicht sagen, dass (natürliche) Sprache einfach nicht [assoziativ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assoziativgesetz) ist.

---

Schon im speziellen Fall von "nicht wollen" gibt es mehrere mögliche Bedeutungen, die man durch einen Nachsatz klarer machen könnte:

- Ich wollte nicht hierher fahren, sondern *du* wolltest es
- Ich wollte nicht hierher fahren, sondern *musste* hierher fahren
- Ich wollte nicht hierher fahren, sondern *woanders* hin
- Ich wollte nicht hierher fahren, sondern hierher *laufen*

Daran sieht man, dass das "nicht" sich praktisch auf jedes andere Wort beziehen könnte. Darüber hinaus könnte man natürlich auch etwas sagen wie

- Ich wollte nicht hierher fahren, sondern zuhause bleiben

---

Eine allgemeine Regel, wie man solche Mehrdeutigkeiten umgehen kann, gibt es wohl nicht. Bei *gesprochener* Sprache kann man den Sinn vielleicht durch eine Betonung deutlich machen. In den obigen Beispielen könnte schon ein Betonen des Wortes reichen, auf das sich die Negation bezieht. Allgemeiner, und speziell bei geschriebener Sprache, bleibt einem wohl kaum etwas anderes übrig, als die Aussage genauer auszuführen - etwa durch die oben angedeuteten Ergänzungen, oder eine ganz andere Formulierung.

Comment: Das sehe ich anders. Meines Erachtens bedeutet _Glauben heißt nicht wissen_ nur: das Wort "glauben" ist nicht dasselbe wie das Wort "wissen". Anders sähe es bei dem Satz _Glauben heißt nicht **zu** wissen_ aus. Durch den Infinitiv mit zu wird "nicht zu wissen" zu einer Einheit. Deshalb würde ich den letzten Satz interpretieren als: "Glauben" ist gleichbedeutend damit, etwas "nicht zu wissen".

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Dieses einleitende Beispiel sollte nur verdeutlichen, dass bei einem Satz mit "nicht" oft nicht klar ist, worauf sich das "nicht" bezieht (und worauf nicht :-)). (Man könnte darüber streiten, ob es bei Verwendung des Infinitivs mit 'zu' nicht *"Zu glauben heißt nicht zu wissen"* heißen sollte, aber das schweift dann etwas ab). Ganz im Sinne des Kerns der Frage geht es auch hier darum, wie man zwischen "Ich wollte (nicht fahren)" und "Ich wollte nicht (fahren)" unterscheiden kann.